# Send iOS user to update iOS version

Tags: ios

Is there a way to send a user to the iPhone settings screen - the page where he can update the iOS version. Is this possible?

I want to notify users of old versions of my app the this version is no longer supported and that an iOS update is required to see new versions.

Comment: No according to me you can't re-direct user to iOS update screen, however you can show pop-up with instructions to user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send user to any other part of the settings screen other then your apps part.

**As mentioned by [madmik3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291733/madmik3) might/will actually reject your app because of this.**

<strike>You might want to present the user with a alert telling them they should update there iOS version. But be aware that some device can not longer update and Apple will offer them an older version of you if you allowed it.</strike>

This version should then not give the message of be unavailable.

Comment: I had a app rejected via guideline 10.6 for prompting user to update. The comment said we needed to the built in system. Which I assume means - the app developer should not hit people over the head with it?

Comment: You are probably right, Apple might actually reject for this.

Comment: @madmik3 - what was the reason the app was rejected?

Comment: It is stated in the comment **10.6 for prompting user to update** look it up in the app review guide lines.

Comment: 10.6 reads: "Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected"